# SAS replacing string with string values within a table

Tags: sas

I have this CSV dataset named Cars:

```
Brand, Model, Description, Year, Price, Sale
Toyota, Wish, "1.5, used""", 2018, 120000, 0
Lexus, LX300, "2.0 4wd, leather seat 15"", 2021, 23000, 0
Toyota, Innova, "2.0, 7 seater 4wd, "full spec 12""", 2007, 5000, 0
Honda, CRV, "2.5, 4wd", 2021, 11500, 0
Nissan, Serena, "7 seater, hybrid, used", 2019, 14400, 0
Hyundai, Elantra, "5 seater, turbo used", 2020, 13210, 0
```

I tried to replace , and " under description so that SAS can read it correctly.

```
FILENAME cars '....Cars.csv';
data cars_out;
 infile cars dlm=',' firstobs=2 truncover;
 format Brand $7. Model $7. Description $334. Year 4. Price 5. Sale 1.;
 input@; 
 Year= translate(Year,' ','",');
 input Brand Model Description Year Price Sale;
run;
```

But this doesnt work? any clue on why?

Comment: Did you write the code yourself? :-)

Comment: The bottom one yes. The upper one is the similar dataset that i encountered

Comment: What is the problem?  The second line of real data, ignoring the header line, in your CSV example has unbalanced quotes. Is that the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Make sure to use the DSD option on your INFILE statement. In addition to treating empty values properly this will also remove the quotes from around the quoted values in your file.  However it will not fix improperly formatted lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file is invalid. It has unbalanced quotation marks and embedded commas, causing a problem. If you open the file up in Excel, you will see it is invalid.

[image]

After manually fixing the file within Excel, the correct .csv should look as such:

[image]

Data:

```
Brand, Model, Description, Year, Price, Sale
Toyota, Wish," ""1.5 used""""""",2018,120000,0
Lexus, LX300," ""2.0 4wd leather seat 15""""",2021,23000,0
Toyota, Innova," ""2.0, 7 seater 4wd ""full spec 12""""""",2007,5000,0
Honda, CRV," ""2.5, 4wd""",2021,11500,0
Nissan, Serena," ""7 seater, hybrid used""",2019,14400,0
Hyundai, Elantra," ""5 seater, turbo used""",2020,13210,0
```

After balancing the quotes, SAS can read this correctly using your provided code. The only change I'd make is to increase the formatted length of `price` to 8 so it is not shown in scientific notation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Stu Sztukowski, that also works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach cannot work.  You cannot change the value of YEAR before you have read anything into YEAR.  You need to fix the text in the file for SAS (or anyone) to be able to parse it.

Best would be to re-create the file from the original data using proper quoting to begin with.  When generating a CSV (or any delimited file) you should add quotes around values that contain the delimiter or quotes. Any actual quotes in the value should be doubled to make clear they are not the closing quote.  SAS will do this automatically when you use the `DSD` option on the `FILE` statement.

With your example you might be able to peal off the beginning and the end since they do not appear to have issues.  Then whatever is left is the value of DESCRIPTION.

```
data want;
  infile cars dlm=',' truncover firstobs=2;
  length brand model $20 description $400 year price sale 8 dummy $400;
  input brand model @;
  nwords=countw(_infile_,',');
  do i=1 to nwords-5;
    input dummy @;
    description=catx(',',description,dummy);
  end;
  input year price sale;
  drop i dummy;
run;
```

Results
[image]

You could probably clean things up more:

```
if '""'=char(description,1)||char(description,length(description)) then do;
  description=substrn(description,2,length(description)-2);
  description=tranwrd(description,'""','"');
  if countc(description,'"')=1 then description=compress(description,'"');
end;
```

So with that cleaned up version your source file SHOULD have looked like this for it to be properly parsed as a comma delimited file.

```
Brand,Model,Description,Year,Price,Sale
Toyota,Wish,"1.5,used",2018,120000,0
Lexus,LX300,"2.0 4wd,leather seat 15",2021,23000,0
Toyota,Innova,"2.0,7 seater 4wd,""full spec 12""",2007,5000,0
Honda,CRV,"2.5,4wd",2021,11500,0
Nissan,Serena,"7 seater,hybrid,used",2019,14400,0
Hyundai,Elantra,"5 seater,turbo used",2020,13210,0
```

Comment: and what is the role of dummy in the do statement?

Comment: You need an extra variable to read the individual "words" caused by the mal formed lines so they can be concatenated into DESCRIPTION.  Using a name like DUMMY let's you know it is a variable intended to be discarded.

Comment: Thanks Tom. For the countw function for nwords, does it means it is counting how many delimiters are there? and for nwords-5 means get the first 2 delimiters (for brand and model)?

Comment: It is counting the number of "words" in the line, which should be one more than the number of delimiters.